# How to set up Night light mode on one monitor and leave the second one Normal

Tags: windows-10, dark-mode

(Windows 10) In a typical dual monitor set-up, how to set up night light mode on one monitor and leave the second one unchanged?

Also, I don't want to use a third party software for this simple task.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear so. Windows has no understanding of "simple task".

However, you may be able to do something similar usuing your graphics driver options according to [R_1 on Tom's hardware forums](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/windows-10-night-light.3537125/), but this will depend of the GPU you're using. These can often be accessed by clicking the relevant driver in the system tray.

Nevertheless, [there doesn't seem to be a windows option to do this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/8tx64j/can_i_disable_night_light_on_one_display_monitor/). See the Display settings and night light settings below.

[Windows 10 Display Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pThrL.jpg)

[Windows 10 Night Light Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIaps.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

While Windows doesn't come with this feature built-in, you can install f.lux from the Microsoft Store. Once it's installed, open the app, click on the hamburger menu, and you'll find an option to disable it. From there, just pick which monitor(s) you want it disabled on.

f.lux:
https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N9KDPHV91JT?ocid=pdpshare